# fetching instances from rescue/raise error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

Suppose I have a gem where some method is called

```
      def grit
          @grit ||= Grit::Repo.new(path)
        rescue Grit::NoSuchPathError
          raise NoRepository.new('no repository for such path')
      end
```

Suppose now I call from my rails app this method. Is there a way to fetch this `NoRepository` instance from my app or am I supposed to change this method in order to make it return this instance  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by `fetch` `NoRepository` instance.  Basically the way you reference that instance of `NoRepository` is by rescuing from that error.

The code calling the `grit` method and rescuing from `NoRepository`:

```
begin
  grit()
rescue NoRepository => nr
  # Here `nr` is the instance of NoRepository
end
```

Comment: do you mean that if an error occurs when calling `grit()`, exception handling will be delegated to this `rescue NoRepository => nr ... end` you wrote ?

Comment: @user1611830, yes if an error occurs that raises `Grit::NoSuchPathError`.  That's where you'd execute whatever things you'd do if exception of type `NoRepository` was raised, possibly log the error and notify the user or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

`NoRepository` is not an instance of a repository, is an exception raised when `path` don't reference a valid git repository.

That method should work exactly as it is.

If for whatever reason you need to get an instance of the repo without passing by the `grit` helper, you can call directly

```
 Grit::Repo.new(path)
```

passing a path, for example

```
 Grit::Repo.new('/tmp/foo')
```